# aws cli s3 sync command "misses" uploading files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So I am running a simple aws cli sync command.

`aws s3 sync ./MyData/2020 s3://mybucket/MyData/2020`

This particular folder has about 2.7TB of data in it.

To put it simply, I run it and then I discovered by running it again that it "missed" uploading files. The files missed, ranged in size between ~1GB and ~100GB files.

I ran the above command and it synced and "completed" what I thought was all of the data (it didn't error). The problem is...I ran it on the same folder accidentally and it started backing up more data...data I thought that I thought was backed up. I started checking the folder structure on s3 and the sync just straight up missed files that were on the local system. Its almost like it "skipped" folders/fires. Everything in these folders are NOT changing, its just archived data thats not changing that we are just backing up to S3.

I have a bunch of these folders of about this size and it seems about 1/4 of the folders have this same problem of "missed" data. I can determine this by running --dryrun with the same command and it finds a dozen or so files that it needs to upload again.

From the docs of s3 sync, it states

> The s3 sync command copies the objects from the source to the
> destination bucket, if:
>
> ```
> * the size of the objects differs
> * the last modified time of the source is newer than the last modified time of the destination
> * the s3 object does not exist under the specified prefix in the destination bucket
> ```

The files that are being upload just meet the last bullet, they just don't exist on the destination side. Has anyone seen this?

Is there an obvious reason why it would skip files but running it again would allow them to upload?

Comment: Any chance they failed early and you didn't see the failures in the output?

Comment: I don't have the upload logs of the folders unfortunately as I just realized it was happening. I'm saving the upload logs now to see if there are any failures. The 3 folders i've ran the "re-sync" on so far, its been about 50 files and all have synced "successfully" (ran it the second time and then immediately ran the sync again and no files were uploaded).

Comment: You should be checking the return code of the command.  The uploads of those files almost certainly failed and now you have a multipart uploads sitting around.  You can verify this by running `aws s3api list-multipart-uploads --bucket example-bucket` to see if there are any incomplete uploads.

Comment: @AnonCoward im not seeing any .multipart files listed.

Comment: With that command?

Comment: Yeah, I had to modify it for my own purposes but nothing was returned. I assume that I would see .filepart type files as well in the bucket/prefix as well? Or are they hidden somewhere? If so I don't see any.

Comment: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/3273